# Replace map() with reduce() function

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I try to replace `map` to `reduce` but without success. Can you help me rewrite this piese of code:

```
this.tares = this.tares
  .map(tare => {
    let suppliers = [];
    this.organizations.forEach(organization => {
      if (organization.tare_ids.indexOf(tare.id) !== -1) {
        suppliers = suppliers.concat(tare.suppliers);
      }
    });
    return { ...tare, suppliers };
  });
```

My `supplier` variable as an accumulator parameter of a `reduce` function but in this case, I can't figure out how to apply `reduce`. Nested arrays crashing me.

Comment: How do you need your output? If you could add examples of input and output to the question it would be very helpful

Comment: And post the error.

Comment: For a simple `map` that multiples by 2 to get you started..  `a.reduce((a, v) => (a.push(v * 2), a), [])`

Comment: @Keith a slightly more generalised overview `arr.map( x => {/* transform x */})` will turn into `arr.reduce((acc, x) => { let y = /* transform x */; acc.push(y); return acc; }, [])` With that said, I'm not sure why you'd use `.reduce` if `.map` already works.

Comment: Isn't it  the `.forEach` that should be replaced with a `.reduce`? There is no reason to turn the  `.map`  into `.reduce`...

Comment: apart from the syntax challenge, construct is strange: suppliers would be added if an organization does not handle the tare (even though an other organization may).

Comment: @trincot maybe? Your words make sense but I don't know either what the input is, nor what the expected output is. And if you are correct, then I'd replace the `forEach` with `filter` -> `flatMap`  personally, since it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a Set for all `id` and map the array with an object and a check if `id` exists.

```
var ids = this.organizations.reduce(
        (s, { tare_ids }) => tare_ids.reduce((t, id) => t.add(id), s),
        new Set
    );

this.tares = this.tares.map(tare => ({ ...tare, suppliers: ids.has(tare.id) ? tare.suppliers : [] }));
```